# Google Maps API missing street names

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, geocoding, google-geocoder

I'm trying to geocode multiple addresses. My problem is that sometimes the address actually exists but Google Maps didn't label that street, so I can't find the geocode.

I want to know if there is some way to add street names with any Google API or any software with an API that will allow me to do this.

For example, if Street 11 doesn't exist, add two coordinates from end to start naming the street. This way the next time I look up, I can find it.

I have found multiple services such as [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com), but they are not even close to Google's geocode accuracy. If I found this software, I could also do batches of addresses in a small period of time.

Answer (score 2):

The tool that was used to edit map data at Google has a name Map Maker.

https://mapmaker.google.com/mapmaker

The bad news is that this tool was deprecated and will be shut down in March 2017. I am not aware about a possible replacement, haven't seen any announce yet.

You can try to follow this help article while Map Maker is still available:

https://support.google.com/mapmaker/?hl=en#topic=1094356

Alternatively you can use the "Report a problem" link on the bottom right corner of the maps.google.com.

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

#### First, a side note for your information:

Geocoding partial addresses or addresses that aren't real (according to the postal service) can result in really weird geocoding information. I can imagine that a lot of partial or unreal addresses don't return results because it is just too hard to guess.

As it is, most geocoding services have to extrapolate latitude and longitude by using information such as street and zip code endpoints, directions, and number of valid addresses on the street. In a lot of ways, there is guesswork involved for everyone. Google often has great geocode information because they have extensive hours driving cars with cameras and sensors marking exact locations of buildings on streets (that information is not obvious from an address). If street names are incorrect, new, old, or some other problem, it makes this "extrapolation" process even harder. Generally, you will see similar enough quality across geocoding APIs and services, and there will still be enough uncommon errors, that choosing your API based on geocoding accuracy should only be done in special cases. It's not common to need exact geocoding precision and most APIs can meet normal geocoding needs (but, in your case, maybe it is necessary, I don't know). Choose APIs based on program design needs. For instance, Google has great business and place search but doesn't validate or verify addresses, while SmartyStreets does.

#### Here are some possible ways to fix the problem:

If you want to get an address added to Google Maps, the best way I've heard of is to [report an error on the map](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088) to Google.

Google has this website for making your maps (https://www.google.com/maps/d), but it might not fit your problem very well.

You can also open [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com), find the location (searching for a latitude and longitude pair, if you have it, will work well on Google Maps), then right click to add a missing place or report an error. (These will be saved in your contributions, which you can view from the menu opened by the three-bar icon menu in the search bar.)

Full disclosure: I worked for SmartyStreets.